# Реализация ToDo Списка на php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

В личном кабинете пользователь может создать список своих дел. Реализация может показаться вам глупой, но мне интересно ваше мнение по поводу того, есть ли смысл в такой реализации и мне кажется, что такая реализация более производительна. 
Вместо того, чтобы таск каждого пользователя добавлять как ряд в БД, при входе пользователя в личный кабинет я делаю запись в БД, а именно такие колонки: "id", "owner", "task". В колонке "owner" - логин пользователя, в колонке "task' будут находиться все задания пользователя. Когда пользователь добавляет таск, то в его колонке "task" добавляется это задание, чтобы разделять задания я создал некий разделитель который выглядит как-то вот так ;-; то есть колонка "task" у каждого пользователя выглядит вот так: "Задание1;-;Задание2;-;Задание3;-;Задание4"
1-й вопрос: Это полнейший бред, или такая реализация имеет право на жизнь?
2-й вопрос: Если это не полнейший бред и я хочу сделать возможность фильтровать задания например по дате или по алфавиту, стоит ли мне добавлять новою колонку в таблицу с названием например taskDate и taskAlphabet?
Не судите строго, так как недавно занимаюсь с Базами Данных.
p.s. я гуглил, но находил только реализацию ToDo списка для одного пользователя.

Comment: У вас на выбор два способа: реляционная модель данных, как вы написали, одна задача - одна строка. Или нереляционный подход, опять же, вы сами все описали, и @d_reseller пояснил. Для поиска по JSON посмотрите [этот ман](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), а чтобы работало быстро, можно сделать индекс, в оф. документации также об этом написано. Предостерегу, что сейчас три форка мускула (mariadb, percona и mysql), и реализация JSON у них разная, нельзя будет легко перенести. MongoDB рассматривали? Там все круче.

Answer (score 1):

Если прям уж хочется хранить список заданий прямо в строке с человеком - делай это в json формате хотя бы.

Пример:

```
[{"task_name":"Задание 1","done":0,"task_date":1540919044},{"task_name":"Задание 2","done":1,"task_date":1540919046}]
```

А вообще по нормальному будет завести отдельную таблицу с полями: уникальный id для каждой задачи, id пользователя создавшего задачу, название, статус, дату и все остальное, что нужно. При такой реализации еще будет удобнее делать выборку по алфавиту и дате прямо в SQL запросе.

Comment: Если будет много пользователей, это не будет нагружать сайт?

Comment: (Я имею в виду кучу записей в бд)

Comment: Зависит от реализации. Хранение json по производительности точно хуже будет

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное мне время :)